# формирование новой структуры дерева по заданной структуре данных

Tags: javascript

Помогите, пожалуйста, разобраться с рекурсией. Задача состоит в том, чтобы из запроса sql сформировать json в определенной структуре.

На вход получаем информацию в таком виде:

```
   const obj = {
    and: [
      {
        or: [
          {
            and: [
              {
                eq: [
                  'rooms.gruppapoploschadi1',
                  {
                    literal: '1.1. До 25'
                  }
                ]
              },
              {
                eq: ['rooms.kolichestvokomnat2', 5555]
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            eq: [
              'rooms.naznacheniepomescheniya4',
              {
                literal: 'Жилая недвижимость'
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        or: [
          {
            eq: [
              'rooms.naznacheniepomescheniya4',
              {
                literal: 'Жилая недвижимость'
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            eq: [
              'rooms.komnaty0',
              {
                literal: '1. Студии'
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
```

На выходе, с сохранением заданной вложенности, нужно получить:

```
 result = {
    type: 'group',
    logic: 'and',
    condition: null,
    children: [
      {
        type: 'group',
        logic: 'or',
        condition: null,
        children: [
          {
            type: 'group',
            logic: 'and',
            condition: null,
            children: [
              {
                type: 'item',
                logic: null,
                children: null,
                condition: { eq: ['rooms.gruppapoploschadi1', { literal: '1.1. До 25' }] }
              },
              {
                type: 'item',
                logic: null,
                children: null,
                condition: { eq: ['rooms.kolichestvokomnat2', 5555] }
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            type: 'item',
            logic: null,
            children: null,
            condition: {
              eq: ['rooms.naznacheniepomescheniya4',
                { literal: 'Жилая недвижимость' }]
            }
          }

        ]
      },
      {
        type: 'group',
        logic: 'or',
        condition: null,
        children: [
          {
            type: 'item',
            logic: null,
            children: null,
            condition: { eq: ['rooms.naznacheniepomescheniya4', { literal: 'Жилая недвижимость' }] }
          },
          {
            type: 'item',
            logic: null,
            children: null,
            condition: { eq: ['rooms.komnaty0', { literal: '1. Студии' }] }
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
```

Важно учесть, что объект с типом group может иметь либо and либо or, то есть он точно не сможет иметь condition, но точно будет иметь children и logic. В свою очередь объект с типом item, будет иметь condition, но не будет иметь children и logic.

У меня получилось обработать вариант запроса, если без вложенности, вот начало, но как прописать все дальше, я не знаю

```
  const firstLogic = Object.keys(obj)[0]
  const children = Object.values(obj)[0]

  const whereObj = {
    type: 'all',
    logic: 'and',
    condition: null,
    children: []
  }

  const child = (object) => {
    Object.values(object).forEach((item) => {
      const logic = Object.keys(item)[0]
      if (logic !== ' or' || logic !== 'and') {
        whereObj.children.push({
          type: 'item',
          logic: null,
          condition: item,
          children: null,
        })
      } else {
        child(item)
      }
    })
  }
  child(children)
```

Answer (score 0):

Вроде получилось вот так, хотелось бы поаккуратнее, конечно, но хотя бы работает

```
  const child = (obj) => {
    const res = []

    for (let j = 0; j < obj.length; j++) {
      const logic = Object.keys(obj[j])[0]
      const ch = Object.values(obj[j])[0]

      res.push({
        type: logic === 'and' || logic === 'or' ? 'group' : 'item',
        logic: logic === 'and' || logic === 'or' ? logic : null,
        condition: logic === 'and' || logic === 'or' ? null : obj,
        children: logic !== 'and' && logic !== 'or' ? null : child(ch),
      })
    }
    return res
  }

  whereArr.children = child(children)
```

Answer (score 0):

Предложу вот такой вариант обхода объекта у которого значения это массив и каждое значение в массиве это объект с массивом...

```js
const startData = {
    and: [
      {
        or: [
          {
            and: [
              {
                eq: [
                  'rooms.gruppapoploschadi1',
                  {
                    literal: '1.1. До 25'
                  }
                ]
              },
              {
                eq: ['rooms.kolichestvokomnat2', 5555]
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            eq: [
              'rooms.naznacheniepomescheniya4',
              {
                literal: 'Жилая недвижимость'
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        or: [
          {
            eq: [
              'rooms.naznacheniepomescheniya4',
              {
                literal: 'Жилая недвижимость'
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            eq: [
              'rooms.komnaty0',
              {
                literal: '1. Студии'
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }

const whereObj = {
  type: 'all',
  logic: 'and',
  condition: null,
  children: []
}

function getRes(obj) {
  for (let i in obj) {
    if (i === 'and' || i === 'or') {
      return obj[i].map(item => {
        return {
          type: 'group',
          logic: i,
          condition: null,
          children: getRes(item)
        }
      })
    } else {
      return {
        type: 'item',
        logic: null,
        children: null,
        condition: obj
      }
    }
  }
}

whereObj.children = getRes(startData);
console.log(whereObj);
```